# How do I show same indent json content in html using flask

Tags: python, json, flask, newline, indentation

So I'm not sure how to do this, and I'm not sure how exactly to describe it.

So I have a flask project that reads out of a json.

my json is reminisant of this

```
{
    "monday": {
        "2:00": {
            "Person A1": "123-456-7890",
            "Person B1": "123-456-7890"
        },
        "2:30": {
            "Person A2": "123-456-7890",
            "Person B2": "123-456-7890",
            "Person C2": "123-456-7890"
        },
        "3:00": {
            "Person A3": "123-456-7890",
            "Person B3": "123-456-7890",
            "Person C3": "123-456-7890"
        },
        "3:30": {
            "Person A4": "123-456-7890",
            "Person B4": "123-456-7890",
            "Person C4": "123-456-7890"
        }
    }
}
```

Let me be clear by saying I do not want a table, I just wanna show this json, I would like to show this in a render_template. and keep the exact indents,

This is what I tried in my python:

```
        with open('st.json') as jsonfile:
          data = json.load(jsonfile)



        data = str(data)
        data = data.replace(", ", ", <br> ")
        return render_template("admin/dashboard.html", name=request.form.get("name"), data=data)
```

and just `{{ data | safe }}`  in my html

Don't ask why I need a render_template, I just do for further improvement.

When I do this I get an odley deformed json. It looks more like a multilined one, but doesn't have the indent's and other stuff. How would I get this to work

Comment: Surround it in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: You can also have a look at [json pretty print](https://www.journaldev.com/33302/python-pretty-print-json)

Comment: Don't forget to improve your HTML!

Comment: I know, lol. I'm aldready using a stylesheet so it's not an issue. and the {{ data | safe }} is a degradion. Theres a bit more code to it lol. If you couldnt tell from the python code. its a admin dashboard. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

@Klaus D, in the comments gave the answer and I wanted to tell everyone.

In the html say `<pre>` and `</pre>` before and after the html. This will display it perfectly.

You can also alternatively use [pretty print](https://www.journaldev.com/33302/python-pretty-print-json), but I havent tried it yet,